# shadow box css arrow/bubble element

Tags: html, css

I need to box shadow the contour of the following bubble.

```
<div class=speech-bubble-dark></div>

.speech-bubble-dark {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  width: 300px;
  top: 55px;
  left: -100px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.speech-bubble-dark:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 0;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
```

edit: code was wrong, copied some testing I was doing.

https://codepen.io/iasisalomon/pen/PopREzO

Comment: Use drop-shadow on your after `filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));` you can use it on the main bubble too if it’s causing you issues.

Comment: I miss copied the code, the after part was some testing I was doing, corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but for some reason when we talk about shadows, it concerns another side of the page, I believe.
Have found three options, but solutions may be better using other CSS properties
The first solution is to do some manipulations with the color

```
.speech-bubble-dark {
      position: absolute;
      background: #fff;
      box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      border-radius: 0.4em;
      width: 300px;
      top: 55px;
      left: -100px;
      z-index: 999;
    }
    
    .speech-bubble-dark:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 50%;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border: 15px solid transparent;
      border-bottom-color: #eef;
      border-top: 0;
      margin-left: -15px;
      margin-top: -15px;
    }
```

The second one, as was mentioned in the comment above to use filter: drop-shadow, but with the shadow of another bubble. This is not a very nice visual

```
.speech-bubble-dark {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 7px 5.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  width: 300px;
  top: 55px;
  left: -100px;
  z-index: 999;
}


.speech-bubble-dark:before  {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #eee;
  border-top: 0;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
.speech-bubble-dark::after {
    content: ' ';
    width: 98%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2.5px;
    right: 1%;
    border-radius: 1em;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

And the third one must be the best in my view

```
.speech-bubble-dark {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  border:1px ridge rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 300px;
  top: 55px;
  left: -100px;
  z-index: 999;
}


.speech-bubble-dark:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #eef;
  border-top: 0;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
.speech-bubble-dark::after {
    content: ' ';
    width: 98%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    right: 1%;
    border-radius: 1em;
    box-shadow: 0 -0.1 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```